# How to merge the list elements

Tags: python

**Input**

```
['select', '*', 'from', 'ak','.','person']
```

I need to create a dictionary and merger the element after `from`

**Expected Output**

```
['select', '*', 'from', 'ak.person']
```

Code is below

```
m = []
for i in a:
    if '.' == i:
        ind  = a.index('.')
        m.append(a[ind-1] + a[ind] + a[ind+1])
    else:
        m.append(i)
```

My output >> `['select', '*', 'from', 'ak', 'ak.person', 'person']`
Expected is  `['select', '*', 'from', 'ak.person']`

Comment: Will the elements that have to be merged always be after `from`?

Comment: @vnk , not really you can say like `['select', '*', 'from', 'ak','.','person' where ]` `from` till `where`

Comment: Updated the code I've added. Do check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively short:

```
arr = ['select', '*', 'from', 'ak','.','person']
ind = arr.index('from') + 1
# we join the initial array until 'from' then joining the rest:
print(arr[:ind] + ["".join(arr[ind:])])
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop here checks if the previous element is 'from' and if so, it joins the following three elements that comes after it. 
This should work for the test cases that follow the same pattern like you've given (also including longer queries with `where` mentioned in the updated question) .

```
a = ['select', '*', 'from', 'ak','.','person']
m = []

while i< len(a):
    if a[i-1] == "from":
        m.append("".join(a[i:i+3]))
        i+=3
    else:
        m.append(a[i])
        i+=1
```

**Output**

```
['select', '*', 'from', 'ak.person']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I first extracted a sub-list after 'from' and merged that.

```
orig = ['select', '*', 'from', 'ak', '.' ,'person']

from_pos = orig.index('from')
sublist = orig[from_pos+1:from_pos+4]

new_string = ''
for txt in sublist:
    new_string += txt

new_list = orig[0:from_pos+1]
new_list.append(new_string)
print(orig)
print(new_list)
```

And if you have any where clause or group by after that, you can try this -

```
orig = ['select', '*', 'from', 'ak', '.' ,'person', 'where', 'filter', 'group', 'by']

from_pos = orig.index('from')
sublist = orig[from_pos+1:from_pos+4]

new_string = ''
for txt in sublist:
    new_string += txt

new_list = orig[0:from_pos+1]
new_list.append(new_string)

where = orig[from_pos+4:]
new_list = new_list + where
print(orig)
print(new_list)
```

You get -
`['select', '*', 'from', 'ak.person', 'where', 'filter', 'group', 'by']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def my_func(my_list):
    lp=my_list[(my_list.index('from')+1):(len(my_list))]
    ans=my_list[0:(my_list.index('from')+1)]+["".join(lp)]
    return ans

my_func(['select', '*', 'from', 'ak','.','person'])
```

**Output:**

```
['select', '*', 'from', 'ak.person']
```

---

**Alternate Solution:**

```
def sub_func(my_list):
    lp=my_list[(my_list.index('.')-1):(my_list.index('.')+2)]
    ans=my_list[0:(my_list.index('.')-1)]+["".join(lp)]+my_list[(my_list.index('.')+2):(len(my_list))]
    return ans

def my_func(my_list):
    lst=my_list
    for i in range(my_list.count('.')):
        lst=(lambda x: sub_func(x))(lst)
    return lst

my_func(['select', '*', 'from', 'ak','.','person','where','foo','.','bar', '=', '30'])
```

**Output:**

```
['select', '*', 'from', 'ak.person', 'where', 'foo.bar', '=', '30']
```

This solution targets any elements separated by a period and joins them. Unlike the original solution, it will function with lists containing multiple periods and with lists that do not use a 'from' statement.

Answer (score 0):

Golf answer:

```
print(a[:(i:=(a:=['select', '*', 'from', 'ak','.','person']).index('from')+1)]+[''.join(a[i:])])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).